# Pin Swapping Not Available?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pins, error

I am a bit of an Altium novice. Designing a board and trying to use the "Route Guide" in PCB ActiveRoute. However, when I try to lay out a guide with selected pads and hit ActiveRoute, nothing happens and I get the "Pin Swapping Not Available - Project needs to be saved".

- Each component has been configured for pin swapping
- Each component has Enable Pin Swapping
- Pin Swap Routing is selected in PCB ActiveRoute
- Allow Pin-Swapping is allowed in Project Options, specifically Adding / Removing Net-Labels and Changing Schematic Pins

I have definitely saved my design... I have ran the optimizer for pin swapping and it worked well, but now at a loss on how to get the routing done, as doing it manually would take a long time. Any thoughts? Using Altium v21.6.4 build 81.

Comment: I think you’ll find most professionals do not use the autorouter in Altium! Sorry, not an answer to your question.

Comment: @Kartman No worries - I have been watching videos and noticed that, I liked the active route because it could set guides and do some of the interactive multirouting pretty well. But perhaps I should just do it by hand instead.